# Sunspot solr searching rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Please help with Solr search.
He delete duplicate "contacts", and not searching by one letter.

```
Model:  searchable do
          text :name
        end
controller:     query = params[:search]
                  @search = Sunspot.search [Contact] do |f|
                    f.fulltext query
                    f.keywords query
                  end
                @contacts = @search.results
```

And standart view from railscasts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure I understand, but I think I get one of the problems.

If you add the term:  `contacts:contact1`

followed by the term:  `contacts:contact2`

to the same document, the result will be a field:  `contacts:contact1 contact2`

The field name serves as something of a key to the data.  The same document can't have two fields with the same key.  If you need to be able to fetch distinct contacts from the database, either store each with a different name, or add a delimiter so that you can split them apart once you have fetched the combined field.

As far as searching with one letter, are you performing a prefix or wildcard search to fetch longer fields, like:

```
contacts:B*
```

And it isn't working for some reason?

Or perhaps you have been trying to match the term 'a', or something like that, which could be eliminated by the StopFilter being used?